# Visual Studio Service Pack 1 hides controls that have a visibility set

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

I noticed that after Service Pack 1 was installed to Visual Studio 2010, the XAML designer no longer displays a datagrid that has its visibility controlled by a checkbox using a bool to visibile converter. If I remove the visibility setting from the datagrid, the datagrid is now visible. Is there a way to work around this in design mode?

Comment: If you want WPF designer, it is generally better to use Microsoft Blend, it has much wider capabilities. And in VS just write XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, I just needed to add this to my bool to visible converter:

```
if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject()))
                {
                    return Visibility.Visible;
                }
```